# Two Tail Hypothesis test

Tags: statistics

Use a .01 significance level, a two tail test and the following data to test the hypothesis the proportion of seniors who support Obama equals the proportion of freshmen who support Obama.

```
   senior  freshman
n    50       60
x    16       35
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels bizarre question. Which tests have you learnt? This may not be what you wanted , but the most standard type of test used is a contigency table.

$H_0$: there is relationship between freshmen and seniors in probability of supporting Obama

The test I would use, you can find it in the links below

http://math.hws.edu/javamath/ryan/ChiSquare.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table

Comment: Our teacher hasn't taught us anything. We are basically teaching ourselves. I was confused about what test to use. Not sure if you're right but I appreciate the help

Comment: @Shaily it would be very useful, if you can at least define what $n$ and $x$ are.

Comment: n is the population and x is the number out of the population which supports Obama

Answer (score 1):

For this, you would want to complete a two sample t-test, where we assume that the difference in proportions is equal to zero.

Before any test can be done, however, there are conditions to check - normality, independence, and randomness. $n(p)$ and $n(1 - p)$ are both above zero for both samples, meaning that the distribution is likely normal. Because there are millions of seniors and freshmen students, independence is not a worry. Finally, we will have to assume that the samples are simple random samples.

Let's denote the senior proportion as $p_s$, and the freshmen as $p_f$; thus -

$H_o: p_s - p_f = 0$

$H_a: p_s - p_f \neq 0$

Generally, in statistics, the claimed distribution's proportion is estimated to be $\frac{x_1 + x_2}{n_1 + n_2}$, and so we will say that $\hat p \approx  0.46$. The standard deviation for the claim is calculated as $\sqrt{n_1n_2(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})}$; this means that our standard deviation is approximately equal to $0.0824$.

With the claimed proportion and standard deviation, we can find what the chance of getting these samples were, assuming there is no difference.

First, we standardize the score that we have (which, in this case, is $0.58 - 0.32 = 0.26$). Standardizing, we get $\frac{\hat p - p_o}{\sigma_o}$, which equals $3.15$.

This means that the sample is about 3 standard deviations from the mean. Straight up, at this point we know that it's going to be a very low percentage; but let us continue.

Checking a normal probability distribution table, we find that the percent chance of a value equal or higher than this is $1 - 0.9992 = 0.0008$ - we then double this chance, as we are doing a two-tailed test; this results in $0.0016$. Thus, there is about a $0.16$% chance that we would come about this sample if the claim was true.

Because this chance is lower than the significance level, we can reject the null hypothesis, and thus claim that the proportion of seniors that support Obama is not equal to the proportion of freshmen that support Obama.

Comment: no, this is wrong, n is the number of freshman, x is the number of people supporting obama. Before any test can be done, however, there are conditions to check - normality, independence, and randomness. n(p) and n(1−p) are both above zero for both samples, meaning that the distribution is likely normal. Because there are millions of seniors and freshmen students, independence is not a worry. Finally, we will have to assume that the samples are simple random samples. Makes no sense. Sorry, but this is just plane wrong. You are appleaing to CLT here, but I don't think it is right thing to do.