# help on two tail test

Tags: statistics

Use the data below on the enthusiasm for Obama to test the hypothesis that the means are equal for men and women.   Use .01 significance level and  a two tail test.

```
       women   men
  mean  57     62
  var   64     81
   n    50     40
```

Comment: why 2 quick consective question on pretty much the same topic? it would help if you tell people what you have learnt or where you are stuck...

Comment: We haven't learned anything. Our teacher didn't teach us at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Tail Hypothesis test](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357639/two-tail-hypothesis-test)

Comment: @Micah: Thanks for letting me know its a duplicate. I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be a $t$-test with unequal variance, the formula can be found her:

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm

As a side note: I am pretty sure the contigency table is what you should be using for the other one. Your question would receive more attention if you indicated a bit more what you tried or already know.

Comment: I haven't tried some of the problems because I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Stackexchange is literally my teacher right now. Also thank you soo very much for helping me.